# Powershell clipboard problems

Tags: powershell, outlook, clipboard

When I copy files from Microsoft Outlook my script doesn't work.

```
$dirs = get-clipboard -format filedroplist
foreach($dir in $dirs){
    Copy-item $dir -destination 'c:\test'
}
```

`$dirs` is empty

Any ideas?

Comment: Professor, how did you filled the clipboard with a file drop list?

Comment: In Outlook choose file in message and mouse right click -> copy

Comment: Your PowerShell script works. You can check it by selecting some files in the Windows Explorer and copy the file drop list to the clipboard (context menu: Copy). In that case you get the files copied to the destination. It looks like failed to create a file drop list in Outlook.

Comment: You can also use `$clipboard = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetDataObject()` to get full control to the clipboard. Use `Get-Member` to identify the members. The method `ContainsFileDropList` indicates if you have successfully added the file drop list from your source application.